# Password Prompt issue when trying to connect to GitHub

Tags: xcode, git, github

I have configured my account on GitHub to host my Xcode project.
I followed [this article on GitHub official website](http://help.github.com/mac-set-up-git/). All goes fine until i tried to
test everything out:

```
$ ssh -T git@github.com
```

Here, i get the following password prompt : `Enter the password for the SSH key <<id_rsa>>`

I opened the `id_rsa` file with a text editor, but i didn't find such password.

My Mac OS is `Lion 10.7.4`

Am i missing something? thanx in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you created your ssh keys, you entered a passphrase. This is the password you are looking for.

If you don't want to enter any password, you can just do your ssh keys again and specifying no passphrase.

Comment: Oh yeah, i forgot about it, thanx a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

If you configured your SSH passphrase with the OS X Keychain, you may be able to recover it.

https://help.github.com/articles/how-do-i-recover-my-ssh-key-passphrase/